# RDLC - VS Report New Page

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a master reports that use 2 or more subreports. How I can make each subreport to start on a new page?

I'm using everything in list

[image]

Comment: could you add a group of some sort and then have a page break in between each group perhaps? Just a thought

Comment: @Harry i'm using a group on main list and this work a fine, but the problem is page break.

Comment: how about in the design of your subreport1 you add an extra page break at the end..  (page break after group).. so when it is rendered from the main report.. there will be a page break between subreport1 and subreport2